# ISO standard icons for toolbar (Windows)

Tags: windows, icons

Does anybody know of a source of icons for Windows which come close to the standard / main stream icons on this platform? I am talking of icons you find in a toolbar like 'file open', 'save', 'print' or 'zoom'.

Any help or link will be highly appreciated.

M'

Comment: You can find them in the Windows API. Can't look it up at the moment.

Comment: The documentation for [`LoadImage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadimagea) tells you how to load them, but does not list which icons are available - they expect you to inspect `Winuser.h` and figure it out from there.